# ASP.NET - Finding Label Control in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, label

I'm having a problem trying to find a label control that is inside a GridView.
Please see my codes below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" MaxLength="10" Width="70" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgScoreDate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.gif" />
                <ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender ID="txtDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDate" PopupButtonID="imgDate" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is my .cs file:

```
protected void LoadGridView()
{
    //Do something else

    foreach (GridViewRow row in MyGridView.Rows)
    {
        //Tried A
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblName = row.FindControl("lblName") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label;
        lblName.Text = "Name";

        //Tried B
        ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)row.FindControl("lblName")).Text = "Name";
    }
}
```

I debug this code and it seems to work fine because my breakpoint is being hit each time the debugger runs. It even loops through my `foreach` block the same count as to how many rows my GridView has.

But I don't understand why my `lblName` control doesn't get the "Name" text as a value? Am I missing anything here? I tried both `//Tried A` and `//Tried B` methods but they both doesn't update my label's text.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call `LoadGridView` inside `PreRender`. Basically, you want to call it after `GridView` is bound with data.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadGridView();
}
```

Look at `PreRender` event of [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: I'll pick this as the answer since you gave me the idea to look into my code which sets the datasource of the GridView and bounds the data. Apparently, I made a stupid mistake cause these two lines (datasource and binding) were placed below the foreach loop. So basically the foreach runs on a GridView without data in it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On your gridview add:

```
<asp:GridView OnRowDataBound="MyGridView_RowDataBound" ... />
```

Then define `MyGridView_RowDataBound`:

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    Label l = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("lblName");
}
```

What I think is happening is the control is not recreated server side in its current spot.

Comment: Yes, I know this would work. But I was hoping i'd avoid this solution as much as I can for some other reason. I was hoping to make my code above work since I see it being hit by a breakpoint whenever I debug. Thanks, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this 
on .aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" 
        onrowdatabound="MyGridView_RowDataBound" .../>
```

code behind ::

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadGridView();
    }
}

void LoadGridView()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    // dt= call ur database method to get data
    MyGridView.DataSource = dt;
    MyGridView.DataBind();
}

protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lbl_Name = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblName");
        lbl_Name.Text = "Name";
    }
}
```

cheers!